# uninitialize all variables and functions values on activity restart in android

Tags: android

I just want to reinitialize all static and non static function and variable after restarting the app.
I use this, but I failed to got success.

```
Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Try this on onDestroy
 int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);

It will kill all the process on exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear all static members, the code you are using can't help you. It is just restarting Launcher intent, not restarting app. For this you have to kill your app using following code.

```
 int processId = android.os.Process.myPid(); 
 android.os.Process.killProcess(processId);
```

If you are going to use this code do not put it in `onDestroy()` instead you can use onStop() because this callback `onDestroy()` method is called when os is running out of memory and want to relain it(For more info read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)).

If are going to restart app manually, this thing is also not going to help you. Because for restarting you app you will have to launch launcher activity that is not possible after killing app.

You have to simply assign null to all static variables(No need to resent methods).